# Print Matlab output to Unix Console

Tags: matlab

When I run  `matlab -nodesktop -r "run myscript"` a Matlab command window pops up and the output is there, but I would like the output to be directed to the unix console. So how do I get a Matlab script ran from a Unix console to output to the Unix console?

Comment: also look at no jvm and no splash

Answer (score 2):

To output data to console (better to say stdout) you can use MATLAB function [fprintf()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) and run it:

```
user@host $ matlab -nodesktop -r "run new.m; quit"
```

new.m:

```
noise_gain = 0.5;
filter_length = 128;

fprintf('*******************************************************************\n');
fprintf('** Starting processing for noise level %f and filter length %d**\n',noise_gain,filter_length);
fprintf('*******************************************************************\n');
```

It gives output:

```
*******************************************************************
** Starting processing for noise level 0.500000 and filter length 128**
*******************************************************************
```

Also you can send output to file (out.txt):

```
user@host $ matlab -nodesktop -r "run new.m; quit"> out.txt; cat out.txt 

                               < M A T L A B (R) >
                     Copyright 1984-2012 The MathWorks, Inc.
                       R2012b (8.0.0.783) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                 August 22, 2012


To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

*******************************************************************
** Starting processing for noise level 0.500000 and filter length 128**
*******************************************************************
```